# How to identify why different result is calculated in Firefox and in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

In the following code `correctSNILS` is finally `true` in Firefox (which is correct) and `false` in IE7. How to identify why?

```
var value = "02324423703";
var correctSNILS = false;
if (value.length == 11) {
    var controlDigits = value.slice(9);
    var SNILS = value.slice(0, 9);
    if (SNILS < 1001998) {
        correctSNILS = true;
    } else {
        var total = SNILS.length;
        var result = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            result += (total - i) * SNILS[i];
        }
        if (result == 100 || result == 101) result = "00";
        if (result > 101) result %= 101;
        if (result == controlDigits) correctSNILS = true;
    }
}
$("#result").text(correctSNILS);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/4LWVa/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access String as an array in IE7:

```
result += (total - i) * SNILS[i];
```

change that to use **charAt** string function:

```
result += (total - i) * SNILS.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I find such mistakes? Is there any tool which can help me?

Comment: Hmm, can I also do `SNILS = SNILS.split('');`? So it will be an array.

Comment: Yes, you could do **var SNILS = value.slice(0, 9).split("");**.

Comment: If you have IE7+, like I do, you can use the dev tools and set the browser and document modes to IE7 and use the debugger. Dev Tools in IE7 if I recall was/is very shaky and crash-prone. I'd stick to alerts. I'm sure there are other tools out there. Just put alerts in points of execution and narrow down where the weirdness is.